# eslint, async - warning duplicate name post

Tags: javascript, eslint, create-react-app

I boostrapped my project using create-react-app and then added MobX on top.

I have the following code in my mobX store:

```
async post(url, payload, doThrow = false, actionDescription = '') {
    try {
        this.isLoading = true
        const {data} = await this.httpClient.post(url, payload)
        return data
    } catch (e) {
        if (doThrow) throw e
    } finally {
        this.isLoading = false
    }
}

async post(url, payload, doThrow = false) {
    try {
        this.isLoading = true
        const {data} = await this.httpClient.post(url, payload)
        return data
    } catch (e) {
        if (doThrow) throw e
    } finally {
        this.isLoading = false
    }
}
```

and my linter is returning the following error:

> 146:3  warning  Duplicate name 'post'  no-dupe-class-members

Why is eslint treating post as a variable and not as a function?

Comment: in javascript, there really is no distinction between a variable and a function ... you know you can do `var x = function() {}` right

Comment: Duplicate function/method names are therefore also not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined two functions with the same name. You might have written these functions inspired from other languages (method overloading of Java) but Javascript doesn't work that way.

Both functions are same in js and you can send how many ever arguments you want to, to one single method. So, essentially, you can call post with or without `actionDescription`, but it will still execute the second function without ever invoking the first. This is because, class functions are attached to the prototype of the class and hence, the second declaration of `post()` will replace the first.

example -

```
add(a, b, c, d) {
// Do something
}
```

can be invoked as follows -

`add(1)` or `add(1, undefined, 2) or` add(undefined, undefined, undefined, 4)`

even better -

```
add() {
var sum;
    for(var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        sum += arguments[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

can be invoked with any number of arguments to get the expected result.

If you wanted to achieve different things with different functions, then you should rename one of those functions.